# Xamarin.Mac How to get the file path when I launch my app from an associated file?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.mac, file-association

As follows, I edited `info.plist` and set it to associate ".atc" extension in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

[image]

Then, I was able to launch the application by double-clicking the "*.atc" file.

However, I don't know how to get the "full path" in the application by double-clicking the "*.atc" file. Is it written around `AppDelegate.cs`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. I used the following example of a swift project as a reference.

ref. [How to associate existing file type for Mac OS application in XCode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679267/how-to-associate-existing-file-type-for-mac-os-application-in-xcode-7)

First, add the "Document.cs" file, a class derived from NSDocument, to the project.

```cs
using System;
using AppKit;
using Foundation;

namespace AttacheCase
{
  [Register("Document")]
  public class Document : NSDocument
  {
    public Document(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
      // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
    }

    public override void WindowControllerDidLoadNib(NSWindowController windowController)
    {
      base.WindowControllerDidLoadNib(windowController);
      // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
    }

    [Export("autosavesInPlace")]
    public static bool AutosaveInPlace()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void MakeWindowControllers()
    {
        //Override to return the Storyboard file name of the document.
        var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        var wincontroller = (NSWindowController)storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController");
        AddWindowController(wincontroller);
    }

    public override NSData GetAsData(string typeName, out NSError outError)
    {
      // Insert code here to write your document to data of the specified type. 
      // If outError != NULL, ensure that you create and set an appropriate error when returning nil.
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ReadFromUrl(NSUrl url, string typeName, out NSError outError)
    {
        var alert = new NSAlert()
        {
            AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Critical,
            InformativeText = "Information",
            MessageText = url.Path,
        };
        alert.RunModal();

        outError = null;
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

At this time, register the name of `Window Controller` by launching Xcode from `Main.storyboard`.

[image]

Now double click on the "*.atc" file, the application will launch and you will get the full path to the file.

[image]